# Exception while loading xml document

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

I'm developing a windows phone application. While accessing bing maps, exception is occurred while loading an xml document "XmlException - Name cannot begin with '.' character" at the line `XDocument result = XDocument.Load(r);` Help please.

This is my code

```
private void locationtoaddress()
    {
        String url = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/" + latitude + "," + longitude + "?o=xml&key=" + bingKey;
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += wc_DownloadStringCompleted;
    }

    void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string s = e.Result;
        XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(new MemoryStream(UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s)));
        XDocument result = XDocument.Load(r);
        var abc= result.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
        var address1 = from query in result.Descendants(abc + "Location")
                       select new Location
                       {
                           address = (string)query.Element(abc + "Name")
                       };
        Location loc = new Location();
        MessageBox.Show(loc.address);
                }
```

This is the value of s I get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1"><Copyright>Copyright © 2013 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.</Copyright><BrandLogoUri>http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png</BrandLogoUri><StatusCode>200</StatusCode><StatusDescription>OK</StatusDescription><AuthenticationResultCode>ValidCredentials</AuthenticationResultCode><TraceId>a017c5068e364703bc8bdbb58f508d96|SINM001009|02.00.139.700|SINMSNVM001117, 32.151</TraceId><ResourceSets><ResourceSet><EstimatedTotal>5</EstimatedTotal><Resources><Location><Name>NH-49, Sampatti Puram, Madurai, India</Name><Point><Latitude>9.9334483</Latitude><Longitude>78.0918096</Longitude></Point><BoundingBox><SouthLatitude>9.9334153</SouthLatitude><WestLongitude>78.0918519</WestLongitude><NorthLatitude>9.9339407</NorthLatitude><EastLongitude>78.0909383</EastLongitude></BoundingBox><EntityType>Address</EntityType><Address><AddressLine>NH-49</AddressLine><AdminDistrict>Tamil Nadu</AdminDistrict><AdminDistrict2>Madurai</AdminDistrict2><CountryRegion>India</CountryRegion><FormattedAddress>NH-49, Sampatti Puram, Madurai, India</FormattedAddress><Locality>Madurai</Locality></Address><Confidence>Medium</Confidence><MatchCode>Good</MatchCode><GeocodePoint><Latitude>9.9334483</Latitude><Longitude>78.0918096</Longitude><CalculationMethod>Interpolation</CalculationMethod><UsageType>Display</UsageType><UsageType>Route</UsageType></GeocodePoint></Location><Location><Name>NH-49, Sampatti Puram, Madurai, India</Name><Point><Latitude>9.9334153</Latitude><Longitude>78.0918519</Longitude></Point><BoundingBox><SouthLatitude>9.9332373</SouthLatitude><WestLongitude>78.0920988</WestLongitude><NorthLatitude>9.9334153</NorthLatitude><EastLongitude>78.0918519</EastLongitude></BoundingBox><EntityType>Address</EntityType><Address><AddressLine>NH-49</AddressLine><AdminDistrict>Tamil Nadu</AdminDistrict><AdminDistrict2>Madurai</AdminDistrict2><CountryRegion>India</CountryRegion><FormattedAddress>NH-49, Sampatti Puram, Madurai, India</FormattedAddress><Locality>Madurai</Locality></Address><Confidence>Medium</Confidence><MatchCode>Good</MatchCode><GeocodePoint><Latitude>9.9334153</Latitude><Longitude>78.0918519</Longitude><CalculationMethod>Interpolation</CalculationMethod><UsageType>Display</UsageType><UsageType>Route</UsageType></GeocodePoint></Location><Location><Name>Bethaniapuram, Madurai, India</Name><Point><Latitude>9.9334153</Latitude><Longitude>78.0918519</Longitude></Point><BoundingBox><SouthLatitude>9.9334153</SouthLatitude><WestLongitude>78.0918519</WestLongitude><NorthLatitude>9.9345254</NorthLatitude><EastLongitude>78.0910617</EastLongitude></BoundingBox><EntityType>Address</EntityType><Address><AddressLine>Bethaniapuram</AddressLine><AdminDistrict>Tamil Nadu</AdminDistrict><AdminDistrict2>Madurai</AdminDistrict2><CountryRegion>India</CountryRegion><FormattedAddress>Bethaniapuram, Madurai, India</FormattedAddress><Locality>Madurai</Locality></Address><Confidence>Medium</Confidence><MatchCode>Good</MatchCode><GeocodePoint><Latitude>9.9334153</Latitude><Longitude>78.0918519</Longitude><CalculationMethod>Interpolation</CalculationMethod><UsageType>Display</UsageType><UsageType>Route</UsageType></GeocodePoint></Location><Location><Name>Sampatti Puram, Madurai, India</Name><Point><Latitude>9.9328814</Latitude><Longitude>78.0917037</Longitude></Point><BoundingBox><SouthLatitude>9.9328051</SouthLatitude><WestLongitude>78.0919259</WestLongitude><NorthLatitude>9.9328814</NorthLatitude><EastLongitude>78.0917037</EastLongitude></BoundingBox><EntityType>Address</EntityType><Address><AddressLine>Sampatti Puram</AddressLine><AdminDistrict>Tamil Nadu</AdminDistrict><AdminDistrict2>Madurai</AdminDistrict2><CountryRegion>India</CountryRegion><FormattedAddress>Sampatti Puram, Madurai, India</FormattedAddress><Locality>Madurai</Locality></Address><Confidence>Medium</Confidence><MatchCode>Good</MatchCode><GeocodePoint><Latitude>9.9328814</Latitude><Longitude>78.0917037</Longitude><CalculationMethod>Interpolation</CalculationMethod><UsageType>Display</UsageType><UsageType>Route</UsageType></GeocodePoint></Location><Location><Name>Bharathiyar Street, Sampatti Puram, Madurai, India</Name><Point><Latitude>9.9330578</Latitude><Longitude>78.092027</Longitude></Point><BoundingBox><SouthLatitude>9.9328051</SouthLatitude><WestLongitude>78.0919259</WestLongitude><NorthLatitude>9.9332373</NorthLatitude><EastLongitude>78.0920988</EastLongitude></BoundingBox><EntityType>Address</EntityType><Address><AddressLine>Bharathiyar Street</AddressLine><AdminDistrict>Tamil Nadu</AdminDistrict><AdminDistrict2>Madurai</AdminDistrict2><CountryRegion>India</CountryRegion><FormattedAddress>Bharathiyar Street, Sampatti Puram, Madurai, India</FormattedAddress><Locality>Madurai</Locality></Address><Confidence>Medium</Confidence><MatchCode>Good</MatchCode><GeocodePoint><Latitude>9.9330578</Latitude><Longitude>78.092027</Longitude><CalculationMethod>Interpolation</CalculationMethod><UsageType>Display</UsageType><UsageType>Route</UsageType></GeocodePoint></Location></Resources></ResourceSet></ResourceSets></Response>
```

Comment: Perhaps there is a '.' in some name in your xml.

Comment: We can't do much without knowing what the bogus XML looks like. Just surround your call to `XDocument.Load` with a try/catch block and check the content of `s` when the error occurs. That said, your code looks horribly wrong, why aren't you directly writing `XDocument.Parse(s);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're converting the string to UTF-16, even though the `XDocument` is expecting UTF-8.

Either use the right encoding:

```
string s = e.Result;
XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)));
XDocument result = XDocument.Load(r);
```

Or more simply, use directly `XDocument.Parse`:

```
string s = e.Result;
XDocument result = XDocument.Parse(s);
```